# Android - SQLite Integer Primary Key not being added

Tags: android, sqlite, integer, primary-key, auto-increment

**EDIT:**
I found a solution. Apparently if I put "_id" as the nullColumnHack in db.insert

```
dbSave.insert(db.getTable(), "_id", values);
```

then it works. Can anybody explain why?

I have a DB in my application. The text fields work just fine, I can write and retrieve them with no problems. However, my ID column which is an "integer primary key" does not get added to the database.

Here is my DBHelper onCreate

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String CREATE_PASS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_PASS + "("
            + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " + KEY_USE + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_PASS + " TEXT" + ")";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_PASS_TABLE);

}
```

Seperate class where I add the values to the DB:

```
private void saveToDB() {

    SQLiteDatabase dbSave = db.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();


    values.put(db.getKeyUse(), edtUse.getText().toString());
    values.put(db.getKeyPass(), edtPassToSave.getText().toString());

    dbSave.insert(db.getTable(), null, values);
    dbSave.close();
    dialog.dismiss();
}
```

and this is where I retrieve the records.

```
private List<Passwords> getPasswords() {
    List<Passwords> passwordList = new ArrayList<Passwords>();

    String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + dbHelp.getTable();
    SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelp.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);


    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            Passwords password = new Passwords();

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), cursor.getString(0), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //password.setId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
            password.setUse(cursor.getString(1));
            password.setPass(cursor.getString(2));

            passwordList.add(password);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    return passwordList;

}
```

However when I try to get the ID and parse it as an int I get a nullPointerException. When I check the ID value with a Toast every single one is blank. What's happening and how do I fix it?

Comment: logcat logs and point where you getting error ...

Answer (score 0):

If you don't put explicitely a value for the ID you should probably set it to auto increment:

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String CREATE_PASS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_PASS + "("
        + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTOINCREMENT, " + KEY_USE + " TEXT,"
        + KEY_PASS + " TEXT" + ")";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_PASS_TABLE);
}
```

Comment: I'll check this out afterwards and let you know if that works as well. However I read in the SQLite documentation that you do not need to specify the AUTOINCREMENT.